# Why $f (x):= \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}\left(1+\left|\ln x\right|\right)}$ only belongs to $L^2(0, \infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

This is a result given in Royden and Fitzpatrick (p. 143). Show that

$$
\int_0^\infty \left[ \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}\left(1+\left|\ln x\right|\right)} \right]^p < \infty
$$

if and only if $p=2$. That is, $f(x) := \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}\left(1+\left|\ln x\right|\right)}$ only belongs to $L^2(0, \infty)$. How is this result derived, please? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order that 
$$\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{(\sqrt{x}\,(1+\log x))^p}$$
is finite we must have $p\geq 2$. On the other hand, 
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{(\sqrt{x}\,(1-\log x))^p}=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{(\frac{p}{2}-1)t}\,dt}{(1+t)^p}$$
is convergent only if $p\leq 2$.